# Mi archivo JavaScript no captura el ID de un elemento en un documento Twig

Tags: javascript, php, html, twig, symfony5

A través de un archivo JS, estoy haciendo algo tan simple como esto: `console.log(document.getElementById("btn_prueba")); console.log(document.querySelector("#btn_prueba"));` pero la consola me devuelve null. Dicho archivo JS está llamado desde una plantilla Twig, pero no encuentra el identificador una vez es renderizado. Sospecho que es algo relacionado con el documento Twig. Me vendría bien la ayuda. Gracias.
Dejo ambos documentos:

**Archivo Twig:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Documentación{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="margin-left-1-100 margin-top-1-100 cairo_font">Documentación</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <table class="table text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Categoría</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Resuelto</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for articulo in articulos %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ articulo.titulo }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.categoria }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.tipo }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.fecha ? articulo.fecha|date('Y-m-d') : '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.resuelto ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
                <td>
                   {#  <a class="btn btn-secondary linkModal" data-src="{{ path('modal_mostrar', {'id':articulo.id}) }}">Mostrar</a> #}
                    <button id="btn_editar" class="btn btn-secondary">Editar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">No se han encontrado registros</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a id="btn_nuevo" class="bg-sucess btn btn-primary margin-left-1-100" href="{{ path('articulo_new') }}">Nuevo registro</a>
    <button id="btn_prueba">Botón de prueba</button>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/src/ajax1.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Esperamos que tu código javascript este encerrado en un bloque $(document).ready(función(){}); tu javascript debe ejecutarse una vez el DOM esté listo, para que tú botón 3xista en la pagina

Comment: Era eso justamente, muchas gracias!